# What "verb" to use for "stop flowing" in this context

Tags: word-request, verbs, spoken-english

> Do not let the rain water **(...blank)...** otherwise mosquitoes can emerge as a big problem.

Can I use the verbs like:

> **gather** or **accumulate**?

I would like to know both the **spoken** and **formal.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The idiomatic standard for this context is [*Mosquitoes breed in **standing** water.*](https://animals.mom.me/long-mosquitoes-breed-standing-water-10182.html) So although it's a relatively uncommon verb form in other contexts, I suggest *Don't let the rain water **stand**, otherwise mosquitoes...*

Answer (score 1):

You could easily use `gather`. `Accumulate` is a little bit more formal, but would also get the point across.

You might also want to think about using the verb `to pool` as in `Pooled rain water will easily become a breeding ground for mosquitoes.`